# java.io.NotSerializableException: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject when STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to client

Tags: jsf, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I set `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `client` on Weblogic 12c (12.1.1.0) using `@EJB` in ManagedBean, I got the following exception:

```
<Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application> <BEA-000000> <Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
...
```

At ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean()
@ViewScoped
public class TestMB implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4760453378399618429L;

@EJB
private TestFacade testFacade;
```

UPDATE:

In the XHTML, using `<h:form/>`, the error will appears.

Comment: This is not the expected behavior. This looks much like a bug in WebLogic, that it doesn't inject serializable EJB proxies. It should work just fine if you test on a different server, e.g. WildFly.

Comment: I believe that is a bug with Weblogic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a solution to use `@ViewScoped` with `EJB`. It seems that `@ViewScoped` do not support EJB with `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` setted to `client`.

To resolve this I have both options:

1. Do not use `@ViewScoped`, choosing `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped` instead
2. Use `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` with `server` paramether